# How to identify users without using login, cookies, or IP-detection like this site

Tags: session, cookies, ip, uniqueidentifier

We want to limit votes on a thread to one per user. Once you vote, you cannot vote again. Even login systems can be defeated, so we're curious what the options are without login systems.

Other SO posts address identifying unique users, and those are helpful, but a system like the one employed by http://codehookup.com would be sufficient for our purposes.

They don't seem to use cookies because they recognize users across browsers, and from our preliminary testing, it doesn't appear like they use IP-based detection.

How are they doing it?